# What is new "Reset on new activity" option about on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Google analitycs announced today their new policy about data retention

[Google Analytics Data Retention](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=it)

Along with the option for choosing how long data will be stored (I chose do not delete data, obviously), there is an option "Reset on new activity".

I cannot find info about what is this option about. What they mean by 'activity'? If I don't switch it off, the option could be reset and data deleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the counter for data retention is reset when the user visits the page again.

Image your retention period is set to 15 months.

User visits once = after 15 months the data is purged.

User visits. One month later the user visits a second time = second visit resets the counter, effectively user data is retained for 16 months in total.